# Formatting Strings

Tags: android, string-formatting

People often link the following for explaining formatted strings, Can anyone show me a working example of how to use this?

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
```

Comment: `String result = getResource().getString(R.string.welcome_messages), "I am a string", 10);`

Comment: start from [official android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

well the name of the string is "welcome_message", for example you want to add that formated text into component, just edit layout.xml, find your component, and set the text on component to use that string

```
component < ....
android:text="@string/welcome_message
... />
```